# Is it possible to have two .html files that make one file

Tags: html, google-app-engine, jinja2

I am currently learning how to make website at Google App Engine with Python 2.7 and Jinja2, and I was wondering is it possible to make two separate HTML files that will make one file.

In main HTML file I want to have basic layout of page (this HTML has main menu, header, footer, ...), and in the other HTML file I want to have a more detailed look (HTML file for main page, HTML page for posts, ...).

Sorry I am not a native english speaker, so sorry if I wrote question bad.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already noticed (by the jinja2 tag) what you want is some template engine. For jinja2 see the examples in the [GAE docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates). Additionally, [in this post](http://www.untilnil.com/2010/08/appenginetemplates2/) there are examples for some other template engines that work on GAE.

Comment: Also have a look at the actual jinja2 docs specifically template inheritance http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#template-inheritance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if your server is Apache, you can use SSI (Server Side Includes).

In your first file:

```
<!--#include virtual="second-file.html" -->
```

Comment: The user specifically said he/she was working with GAE, so Apache is not available.

Comment: it can all be done with jinja2 have a look at template inheritance  http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#template-inheritance and apache SSI is not relevant.

Comment: Please star feature request to support SSI on AppEngine: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9696